# Listview - single choice mode does not work on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having trouble implement single choice mode into ListView. I have spent almost two day solving this problem.

Problem is when I click on checkBox it will not check - it just blink, but on some devices it works.

Code below does work on Samsung galaxy s3(android 4.1.2), Vodafone 975N (android 4.1.1) and some other,but does NOT work on Lenovo P770(4.1.2) and Samsung Young(android 4.4.2).
Can somebody please tell me where could be the mistake?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_calendars_for_locks_of_group);
    ...

    final ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.list_item_with_radiobutton, null).findViewById(
            R.id.listToggleableRadioButton);
    check.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.None));
    check.setTag(0L);

    listView.addHeaderView(check);

    reloadData()
    ...

    listView.setItemChecked(positionOfAlreadySelectedCalendar, true);

}

private void reloadData() {
    calendarsInLockCursor = db.getCalendarIdsForLockCursor(lockId);
    Cursor calendarsCursor = db
            .getCalendarsCursor(Database.CALENDAR_TYPE_ACCESS);

    RadioButtonSimpleCursorLocksAdapter adapter = new RadioButtonSimpleCursorLocksAdapter(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
            calendarsCursor, calendarsInLockCursor,
            new String[] { Database.COL_CALENDARS_NAME },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    positionOfAlreadySelectedCalendar = getPositionInCursor(
            calendarsCursor, calendarId) + 1;
}

public static class RadioButtonSimpleCursorLocksAdapter extends
        SimpleCursorAdapter {

    OnClickListener onClickListener = null;
    private Cursor calendarsInLock;

    public RadioButtonSimpleCursorLocksAdapter(Context context, int layout,
            Cursor calendarsTable, Cursor calendarsInLock, String[] from,
            int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, calendarsTable, from, to, flags);
        this.calendarsInLock = calendarsInLock;

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_with_radiobutton,
                parent, false).findViewById(R.id.listToggleableRadioButton);

        return view;
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {

        CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.listToggleableRadioButton);


        Long calId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(Database.COL_CALENDARS_ID));

        check.setText(c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(Database.COL_CALENDARS_NAME)));
        check.setTag(calId);

    }


    public boolean isCalendarInLock(long calendarID) {
        return SelectCalendarForLockOfGroupActivity.isCalendarInLock(
                calendarsInLock, calendarID);
    }

}
```

in R.layout.list_item_with_radiobutton:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:binding="http://www.gueei.com/android-binding/"
android:id="@+id/listToggleableRadioButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:paddingRight="6dip"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textColor="@color/listItemMain"
binding:text="." />
```

Comment: what is error you are facing.

Comment: Thx, I am dumm :-). Added into description.

Comment: You should always call notifyDataSetChanged right after you set an adapter or change the underlying data for starters. It can cause some freaky behavior if you don't.

Comment: I have put it right after setAdapter(adapter), but still does not work. Thanks anyway

Comment: pardon i've meant setListAdapter(adapter)

Answer (score 1):

Flaw was somewhere else. In styles a had overiden checkTextViewStyle. I had to remove clickable=true atrribute. OMG, what a struggle

```
    <style name="checkTextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget">
    <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>  <- !!!This caused the problem!!! 
    </style>
```